# why i have a break line in the beginning of my csv with php?

Tags: php, file, csv, yii2

i keep getting a break line at the beginning of the csv i've create, and in my array there isnt a break line.

here is my code:

```
$file = 'prueba.csv';
$filew1 = fopen($file, 'w');
foreach ($csv as $line) {
    fwrite($filew1, $line . PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($filew1);
Yii::$app->response->SendFile($file);
```

and my out put is like this

[image]

i dont know why, i have try the str_replace() metod, still.

Comment: What's in `$csv`?

Comment: Maybe `trim($line);`

Comment: Since you're creating a CSV file, have you tried using `fputcsv()`? Seems like it could work better for you. (Depends on where $csv comes from, though. At this point it looks like it's probably an array of strings, which won't work with fputcsv, but maybe it could be used earlier in the code.)

Comment: Can you show me the content of variable `$csv` ?
e.g: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($csv); die;`

Comment: its in the $csv ,show the contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fix it, putting a `ob_clean();` at the beginning of the method.